# Adverb -> Adverbial; Adjective -> Adjectival; Verb ->?

Tags: single-word-requests

The noun "adjective" yields the adjective "adjectival"; the noun "adverb" yields the adjective "adverbial"; but the noun "verb" does not yield the adjective "verbal".

What is the word I am looking for?

And, while we're about it, what adjective does the noun "noun" yield?

I guess I would be pushing my luck in asking for the verb-related and noun-related equivalents to "adjectivally" and "adverbially"...

Comment: But "verbal" *does* mean "Of, pertaining to, or derived from a **verb**" (that's OED's definition #6). It's just that we *also* use the same word more generally for "Dealing in or with words, esp. with mere words in contrast to things or realities" (OED's definition #1). They also list "nounal", defined as " Of, relating to, or characteristic of a noun or nouns; that functions as a noun".

Comment: @FumbleFingers The adjective normally associated with *noun* is actually *nominal*, just as the one associated with *pronoun* is *pronominal*.

Comment: a nominal phrase can function as the subject or object of a verb.

Comment: @tchrist: Obviously. But since I had OED open I just thought I may as well throw that one in to mirror "verbal". And let's not forget that even seasoned professionals like John Lawler habitually use terms like "nouny", "nouniness".

Comment: Thank you, all. I didn't think of "nominal" and had never heard of "nounal". Which of the two would be more commonly used by grammarians? I suppose there is no unambiguous alternative to "verbal"?

Comment: @Irefuteitthus [*Nounal* really isn’t used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=noun+modifier%2Cnounal+modifier%2Cnominal+modifier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnoun%20modifier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnominal%20modifier%3B%2Cc0). It depends on the context whether you should use *noun* attributively (e.g., *a noun modifier*) or whether you should use the *nominal* adjective, but for the most part, adjectives are over-rated. Note that there’s also *nominative*, but that’s for something else.

Comment: Even OED's sense 6 for _verbal_ is far too wide on occasion. And _verbal_ also exists as a noun.

Comment: Explore the etymology, from the French words they are derived, and you will have more clues. Very often, etymology is the key.

Answer (score 2):

The answer's a whole lot simpler than you're making it:

**[verbal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/verbal)** - Relating to, having the nature or function of, or derived from a verb;  Used to form verbs: *a verbal suffix*.

**[nounal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nounal)** - Of or pertaining to a noun.

The Free Dictionary lists *verbally* as the appropriate adverb form of verbal.  And it lists *nounally* as the adverb form of *[noun](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/noun)*.

Comment: [*Nounal* is so rare as to be virtually unrecognizable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nounal%2Cnominal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnounal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnominal%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @tchrist That's completely an apples to oranges comparison.  *Nominal* is widely used under it's other definitions.  Nounal has no other definitions.  Based on basics of English grammar, I completely understand what *nounal* is trying to convey without referring to a dictionary.  I think it's hardly unrecognizable.

Comment: Good luck with all those [nounal modifiers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=noun+modifier%2Cnounal+modifier%2Cnominal+modifier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnoun%20modifier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnominal%20modifier%3B%2Cc0) then.